# can we develop pdf file as part of uI in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Can we develop pdf file or word doc as part of UI elements in android. 
The android screen should contain the pdf file as well as progress bar, is it possible? please suggest me.

Regrads
mini.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do a similar thing about a year ago. I couldn't find a solution. Fortunately I was also coding the webservice where the PDFs were originating, so I was able to provide a separate function that returned a PNG (converted from the original PDF) and I used that as a preview. I then provided an intent for the user to open as PDF in their PDF viewer of choice.